# strcat error reading csv file from a struct

Tags: c, csv, struct, strcat

The error I'm getting navigates to the strcat.asm file and sets a breakpoint at main loop entrance.The readFile method I created is breaking just before the strings are tokenized at this strlen loop:

```
while( !feof(fptr) )
    {
        fgets(oneLine, CONTACT_MAX, fptr); // process the next line to be tokenized
        if (oneLine[strlen(oneLine) - 1] == '\n')
        {

            oneLine[strlen(oneLine) - 1] = '\0';
        }
        sn = strtok(oneLine, " , ");
        fn = sn ? strtok(NULL, " , ") : NULL;
        ph = fn ? strtok(NULL, " , ") : NULL;
        co = ph ? strtok(NULL, " , ") : NULL;
```

Anyone have any ideas where I'm going wrong here?

My readFile() is as follows:

```
struct contact *readFile( struct contact *ptrList)
{
    struct contact *head = NULL;
    struct contact *newContact;
    FILE *fptr;
    char oneLine[CONTACT_MAX];
    char *sn, *fn, *ph, *co;
    head = ptrList;



    //open test.csv to be read
    fptr = fopen("test.csv", "r");

    if( fptr == NULL )
    {
        printf("\nCouldn't open %s...", "test.csv");
        return(ptrList);
    }
    fgets(oneLine, CONTACT_MAX, fptr);

    while( !feof(fptr) )
    {
        fgets(oneLine, CONTACT_MAX, fptr); // process the next line to be tokenized
        if (oneLine[strlen(oneLine) - 1] == '\n')
        {
            oneLine[strlen(oneLine) - 1] = '\0';
        }
        sn = strtok(oneLine, " , ");
        fn = sn ? strtok(NULL, " , ") : NULL;
        ph = fn ? strtok(NULL, " , ") : NULL;
        co = ph ? strtok(NULL, " , ") : NULL;

        if ( head == NULL )
        {
            head = (struct contact *)malloc(sizeof(struct contact));
            ptrList = head;
                strcpy(head->fName,fn);
                strcpy(head->sName,sn);
                strcpy(head->phone,ph);
                strcpy(head->company,co);

            head->prev = NULL;
            head->next = NULL;

        }
        else
        {
            newContact = (struct contact *)malloc(sizeof(struct contact));
            head->next = newContact;
            newContact->prev = head;
            newContact->next = NULL;

            strcpy(newContact->fName, fn);
            strcpy(newContact->sName, sn);
            strcpy(newContact->phone, ph);
            strcpy(newContact->company, co);

            head = newContact;
        } // end of (ptrList == NULL)

    } // end of while( !feof(fptr))
    fclose(fptr);
    return(ptrList);
}
```

The format of the file is like this:

> > Surname,FirstName,Number,Company
>
> the Builder,Bob,1234567,Bob's
>
> > Unknown,Scoop,8765645,Bob's

Comment: Didn't check your code, but suggesting from your description it could be a not 0 terminated string that makes the troubble, couldn't it?

Comment: COuld it happen that your first call to strtok has a NULL pointer as parameter? or does your main code avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
head = (struct contact *)malloc(sizeof(struct contact));
            ptrList = head;
                strcpy(head->fName,fn);
                strcpy(head->sName,sn);
                strcpy(head->phone,ph);
                strcpy(head->company,co);
```

You are derefferencing `head` without `head`'s members have been initialized, thats undefined behavior and probably causing your error because `strcpy` is expecting a `\0` terminated array. But since you haven't initialized the members of head, you can't know they are terminated or not. And even if they are, the problem si that `strcpy()` has to read for checking the `\0` and as far it isn't initialized, `strcp()` is reading uninitialized memory anyway.

And finaly a standard quote:

> J.2 Undefined behavior
>
> 1 The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances:
>
> [..]
>
> The value of the object allocated by the malloc function is used (7.20.3.3).

So a solution would be `memset()` head to `0` so the memblock will be everywhere terminated, as long you don't override it.

Comment: Not only this, but in the 'newContact' branch it is the same error.

Comment: So what should I initialize the `head ` to?

Comment: @Brian J that I'm asking my self too.... I guess I jsut mixed something in my head and talked rubbish... just give me a moment to correct my mind...

Comment: No problem,I'm aware now that derefferencing can lead to undefined behaviour but I'm curious as to what the head should be initialized to  so I could better understand the reason for the error.

Comment: @Brian J look edit, now i got what my head tryed me to tell ;)

Comment: @Zaibis,so I would memset before the the head is `malloc` to size of the struct? Also how would I perform the memset?

Comment: Is this the correct format for the memset? `memset(head, 0,sizeof(head));` also is this placed before the malloc?

Comment: @Brian J NO after the memset, before the memset you dont even have an memory area you could memset. and you had to use it as `memset(head, 0, sizeof (struct contact));`as head is a pointer and its size were processor with and not the size of your structure.

Comment: Ok,I tried the memset and placed it after the first while loop but I get an Unhandled exception at `0x0f6fd22f, 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.`

Comment: @Brian J dude... what about read the manpage of memset? I even explained you how to use it, if you place it after the first loop of course you get this exception... I said you HAVE TO USE IT on memory ur process owns.